# Check KeystoneJS Google Maps Config

Tags: google-maps, keystonejs

I use KeystoneJS Framework and I want to setup Google MAPS for my Admin UI.
I have put `keystone.set('default region', 'FR');` in my *keystone.js* and `GOOGLE_BROWSER_KEY="****"` `GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY="****"` in my *.env*

But nothing appear, just buttons on Admin UI:
`Autodetect and improve location on save`
`Replace existing data`

How to check if my setup is ok and why KeystoneJS didn't find latitude and longitude?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

have you tried enableMapsAPI on user model?

```
location        : { type: Types.Location, enableMapsAPI:true }
```

if this is not working for you take a look at the code: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/fields/types/location/LocationType.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added this:
```address: { type: Types.Location, enableMapsAPI: true },```

But change nothing. I didn't find enableMapsAPI in keystone doc...

Comment: do you have this line in keystone.init({     'google server key'     : process.env.GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY, ...?

Comment: Hi, were to you find this? I read the doc, I never find it. So, in my model I put this: `address: { type: Types.Location, enableMapsAPI: true },` and in my keystone.js:

`'google api key': process.env.GOOGLE_BROWSER_KEY, 
'google server key': process.env.GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY, `

but nothing change. They are a DEBUG env?

Comment: I figured it out of the field code, the link for the code is in in my first answer as I edited it. feel free to take a look on the code as the docs are not useful in this case, do some debugging there maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you may want to verify if your key is correct and add some debug code in keystone/fields/types/location/LocationType.js to check if you get correct response for the following request:

```
https.get(endpoint, function (res) {
    var data = [];
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        var dataBuff = data.join('').trim();
        var result;
        try {
            result = JSON.parse(dataBuff);
        }
        catch (exp) {
            result = {
                status_code: 500,
                status_text: 'JSON Parse Failed',
                status: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
            };
        }
        callback(null, result);
    });
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    callback(err);
});
```

Unfortunately Keystone fails silently in case of incorrect reply from Google API.